# Issue in Horizontal Wheel(Custom) DatePicker Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, datepicker

I am creating a **DATEPICKER** which is a Horizontal Wheel(Custom). I am using this [LIBRARY](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel). I want to display like below....

```html
|Thu    |
| |
|06 |
| |
|Aug |
```

But I am getting like below....

```html
Thu 06 Aug
```

I have tried below code.....

MainActivity.java

```
package com.DatePicker.demodatepicker;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import antistatic.spinnerwheel.AbstractWheel;
import antistatic.spinnerwheel.adapters.ArrayWheelAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final AbstractWheel hours = (AbstractWheel) findViewById(R.id.hour_horizontal);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String[] days = new String[30];
        String[] dates = new String[30];
        String[] months = new String[30];
        String[] FinalArray = new String[30];

        for (int i = 0; i <= 29; i++) {
            Calendar BetweenDates = Calendar.getInstance();
            BetweenDates.setTime(c.getTime());
            BetweenDates.add(Calendar.DATE, i);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormate = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy");
            String EachDate = dateFormate.format(BetweenDates.getTime());

            String[] partsOne = EachDate.split(",");
            days[i] = partsOne[0].trim();

            String[] partTwo = partsOne[1].trim().split("-");

            dates[i] = partTwo[0].trim();
            months[i] = partTwo[1].trim();

            String finalValue = days[i] + "\n" + dates[i] + "\n" + months[i];
            FinalArray[i] = finalValue;

            Log.e("Final String: ", finalValue);
        }

        ArrayWheelAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(this,
                FinalArray);
        adapter.setItemResource(R.layout.wheel_text_centered);
        adapter.setItemTextResource(R.id.text);
        hours.setViewAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.DatePicker.demodatepicker.MainActivity" >

    <antistatic.spinnerwheel.WheelHorizontalView
        android:id="@+id/hour_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:selectionDivider="@drawable/divider_dark_gradient_horizontal"
        app:selectionDividerWidth="1px"
        app:visibleItems="3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

wheel_text_centered.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#777777"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Sorry for not uploading screen shot because I can not upload it. It is confidential. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added below lines to TextView in wheel_text_centered.xml file.

```
android:lines="3"
android:maxLines="4"
android:singleLine="false"
```

It is just simple as I though hard.

Comment: What library have you used ? can you let me know how to use in kotlin